GitHub Webhook Not Triggering Jenkins Pipeline
I'm deploying my code to AWS using AWS CDK using Jenkins. When my pipeline is initiated manually, it operates flawlessly; however, it does not initiate when I push changes to my GitHub repository or when the GitHub webhook is meant to initiate it.
The pipeline is still not being started, even though I am getting a 200 response code whenever a push event happens in the GitHub webhook.
My pipeline script is as follows:
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        githubPush()
    }
    environment {
        CDK_DEFAULT_REGION = credentials('CDK_DEFAULT_REGION')
        ...
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'main', url: '<repo url>'
            }
        }
        stage('Verify Tools') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    go version
                    node --version
                    npm --version
                    aws --version
                    cdk --version
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                dir('Backend') {
                    sh 'make build'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Archive Artifacts') {
            steps {
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'Backend/auth-service/bootstrap', fingerprint: true
               .....
            }
        }
        stage('Configure AWS') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                    ....
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                dir('Backend/deploy-scripts') {
                    sh 'cdk deploy --require-approval never'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The issue occurs specifically with the GitHub webhook not triggering the pipeline despite receiving 200 response code. Any assistance with troubleshooting why the webhook is not firing the pipeline as expected would be greatly appreciated
